# Rxjs timer with pause and resume the poll

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a service `HomeService` and has this method in the service

```
getAlerts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.apiService.post(`${this.DASHBOARD_URL}/alerts`);
}
```

so I have a scenario where I have to poll this method every 10 sec to get the new data and polling should happen only on success response and when browser tab is active. When browser tab is inactive, the polling should pause and resume when tab is active.

From the component I am doing this:

```
import {Subscription, timer as observableTimer} from 'rxjs';
import {delay, retryWhen, takeWhile} from 'rxjs/operators';

    private pollAlerts(): void {
             this.pollAlertsRequest = this.homeService.getAlerts().pipe(retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(10 * 1000))))
              .subscribe(res => {
                this.populateAlerts(res.alerts);
                this.alertsTimer = observableTimer(10 * 1000).pipe(
                  takeWhile(() => this.isComponentAlive))
                  .subscribe(() => {
                    this.pollAlerts();
                  });
              });
    }
```

I am able to get the timer done, but not sure how to pause and resume.

Answer (score 1):

Change `takeWhile` to filter

```
private pollAlerts(): void {
             this.pollAlertsRequest = this.homeService.getAlerts().pipe(retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(10 * 1000))))
              .subscribe(res => {
                this.populateAlerts(res.alerts);
                this.alertsTimer = observableTimer(10 * 1000).pipe(
                  filter(() => this.isComponentAlive)),
                  switchMap(()=>interval(1000)),
                     tap(()=>this.pollAlerts());
                 ).subscribe();
              });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now how to I poll only when I get the response back and like the interval.

Comment: switchMap(()=>interval(1000)), edited the answer, but your code can be written better.

Comment: Yes, can you tell me how can I improve my code. That really helps. I am pretty new to the Rxjs.